# Fastest method to screenshot online game in Python

Tags: python, selenium, tensorflow, screenshot

I'm currently trying to build an ANN that can play the online game "Helicopter Game" (see picture below if you're unfamiliar) using only the pixels of screenshots for training.

[image]

I've built similar models in OpenAI Universe but was hoping to try my hand at training directly on an online game instead of using an emulator.

The first thing I tried was to use the Selenium screenshot method to capture 100 screenshots at 10 frames per second.

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Screenshots\shot'+str(i)+'.png')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

But Selenium doesn't seem to be able to handle that kind of speed, it can only capture about 2 or 3 screenshots per second, even when I take away the time delay, and this is before even doing any preprocessing of the images.

Does anyone know of a method faster than what I'm trying to accomplish with Selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a try to the [MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/) module, and more precisely to [that example](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#part-of-the-screen) to only capture the revelant part of the screen.

The module can be used with PIL, Numpy and OpenCV for other work, just check the doc' :)